# How to create a Gizmos which renders the bounds of a BoxCollider2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to draw a `Gizmos` ontop a `BoxCollider2D`, but the `Gizmos` does not show up in the `Scene` view; with no errors in the console.

EDIT: The problem has been solved, I accidentally put the `OnDrawGizmos` `function` in an `Update` `function` so it wasn't showing up.

My current code:

```cs
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size);
}
```

[image: The image of the enemy and no Gizmos.]

Answer (score 0):

When there is an overlap, `Collider` seems to have priority. 90% size makes the `Gizmos.DrawWireCube()` appear.

[image]

test code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public sealed class GizmosTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size * 0.9f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the argument you added into the list, and I still can't see the Gizmos. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: I have got the code working in a separate scene so I just got to find out how to put it in the other scene. Thanks.